# How to join a MYSQL fulltext search with another table?

Tags: mysql

Hello thanks for reading this:

I have a Product Table in which i am carrying out a full text search on but need to combine it with a product image table

```
    SELECT * FROM product  WHERE Match(productBrand,productTags,ProductDiscription,productCondition,productColour,productCat)  Against('top');
```

I need to join by product ID.

My productImage table contains a productID and a productURL;

Answer (score 1):

You can use query something like below-

```
SELECT prd.*,pim.productURL FROM product AS prd 
JOIN productImage pim ON prd.productID=pim.productID 
WHERE MATCH(prd.productBrand, prd.productTags, prd.ProductDiscription, prd.productCondition, prd.productColour, prd.productCat)  AGAINST('top');
```

**Use of Limit:**

```
    SELECT prd.*,pim.productURL FROM product AS prd 
    JOIN productImage pim ON prd.productID=pim.productID 
    WHERE MATCH(prd.productBrand, prd.productTags, prd.ProductDiscription, prd.productCondition, prd.productColour, prd.productCat)  AGAINST('top')
  LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: thanks it worked, if i a product has more than one image two products are returned, where would i insert LIMIT 1 into the statement ?

Comment: at the end just write LIMIT 1;

Comment: I only want to limit the SELECT on the product Image table not the whole result set?

Comment: LIMIT can be implement only on final result of any query...so if you want to limit data only for product image table then you have to make a sub query with limit then you can join with 2nd table....instead you can filter data based on where condition if possible.